# How to set scale_ defaults in ggplot theme?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, scale

I would like to create a theme that has tick marks different from the default, to avoid repeating `+ scale_x_continuous` every time I create a custom plot.

Let's take a simple example, in which I want only tick marks at the limits:

```
A = 1; f = 5; p = 0; d = 0.4
t = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.01)

x = A * sin(t * f + p) * exp(-d * t)
numticks = 1

qplot(x = t, y = x) + theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::trans_breaks("identity", function(x) x, n=numticks) )
```

This looks great (see below), but ideally I would be able to produce the same result without using `scale_x_continuous` as it's clunky. I want to replace `theme_classic()` with `+ mytheme` and that should solve it.

Here's my best attempt so far at a solution:

```
mytheme <- theme_classic() + 
theme(scale_x_continuous(breaks=trans_breaks("identity", function(x) x, n=numticks))
```

Not sure if this is even possible, and happy to keep typing `scale_x_continuous(...)` every time. But it would be even better to change the defaults temporarily or, even better, in a custom theme.

Here's the plot axes I want to produce btw, and I want to produce many such plots (for plotting [harmonographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonograph)):

[image: custom x axis]

Comment: Ps starting point for thinking about this one is probably ggplot2 docs. Can't see the answer here http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/scale_continuous.html

Comment: Adding a list to a plot adds every element of the list, so your theme function could return a list containing the actual theme and a scale.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that's what you want, but this will save you some space:

```
custom_ticks <- function(n) {
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 
    scales::trans_breaks("identity", function(x) x, n=n))
}

p <- qplot(x = t, y = x) + theme_classic() 
p + custom_ticks(2)
p + custom_ticks(10)
```

Comment: Will do - it's recommended in http://meta.stackoverflow.com that you wait "24 to 48 hours" though, so that's what I'll do. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Turning @hadley's comment into an answer

```
mytheme <- list(theme_classic(),
                scale_x_continuous(breaks=trans_breaks("identity", 
                                                       identity, 
                                                       n=numticks)))

qplot(x = t, y = x) + mytheme
```

(I also replaced `function(x) x` with the already existing function `identity`, but that is not a significant change.)